# How does JSF decide which ViewState to use?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I can see in my page source that I have some hidden inputs that contain the `ViewState`. How does JSF decide which one to use?

PS. I am trying to identify the following [bug](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-3166) with JSF 2.2.5-SNAPSHOT, but I am not sure if all of the IDs should been present or JSF has a way of identifying the latest one.

Comment: view state hidden field is attached to every form and all hidden fields get updated when the viewstate change.

Comment: Thanks, this gets me a bit closer to identify the bug. So this means that for some reason only one of the form states get preserved where all 3 should have been(right?).

Comment: There was an old issue that not all view state hidden fields were updated on ajax response and the workaround was to do it manually with javascript that gets called on ajax completion but it was fixed.